# Рендеринг компонентов не обновляется на странице, хотя в useState все есть

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Делаю первый проект на react, еще не совсем разобралась в фреймворке. У меня есть fetch запрос к северу

```
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState('');
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [clouds, setClouds] = useState('');
  const [tempMin, setTempMin] = useState('');
  const [tempMaxs, setTempMax] = useState('');

async function fetchWeather(e) {
    await axios.get(`запрос`)
        .then( res => {
          setRes(1)
          setTemp(res.data.main.temp);
          setName(res.data.name)

          setClouds(res.data.clouds.all);
          setTempMax(res.data.main.temp_max);
          setTempMin(res.data.main.temp_min);
          setWind(res.data.wind.gust);
        })
```

и такой html

```
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            <h1>{Math.round(temp-273.15)}</h1>
            <p>Облачность {clouds}% </p>
            <div>
              <p>Макс.: {Math.round(tempMaxs-273.15)}</p>
              <p>Мin.: {Math.round(tempMin-273.15)}</p>
            </div>
```

Проблема в том, что когда я отправляла повторный запрос на сервер, данные точно обновлялись (я это вижу в react devtools), но этого не  было видно на странице, clouds, mix-max_temp показывают прежние значения. При этом temp и name обновляются без проблем, хотя по сути они идентичны clouds и min-max_temp

Comment: Не должно такого быть, если представленные обрывки кода из одного компонента. Может как то влияет округление и получается одно и то же значение

Comment: @Александра, в приведенных кусках кода даже нет вызова функции fetchWeather()...

Comment: Так же в async-функции и при использовании await axios.get(`запрос`) не используют .then().catch()...